# Can i know how to following for loop works in python, given "n" is the length of list

Tags: python, loops

```
for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
```

I know the loops start from n-1 and steps of -1 which is to go back is used...What I don't understand is how the end index is -1? shouldn't that be 0? as we are going backward?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range It yields values as long as it has not actually reached stop, so it won't actually yield the -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logic is Correct about that being 0, but the `range()` function returns only till the 'end-1' iteration.

So if you pass in 0, you won't be able to get the 1st element of the list as
`range((n-1), 0, -1)` will give only till the index '1' which is the 2nd element of the list...

Comment: Ah! I get it now....so after index 0 the index is -1 ...so it iterates till -1 excluding -1.... Cool Thanks man

Comment: You're always welcome

Answer (score 1):

Please check the explanation in [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), which reads:

> For a negative *step*, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and `r[i] > stop`.

So if you set the second argument to 0, the result would not include 0 itself, which may be incorrect. And if you set the third argument to 0, an error would be raised.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: "If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop."

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

That way, `range(10)` will give you 10 values, which makes some sense, but `10` won't be included. It's not everyone's favourite thing about Python, but it makes sense if you consider is a language that uses zero-based numbering as well. (i.e. the 1st element of a list `xs` is `xs[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

[From the range documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.

The number of items in your loop will be the difference between *start* and *stop* (not including *stop*).

In your example, since the *stop* value is -1 and *step* is -1, then the last item in your loop will be 0 instead of -1 as you expected.